# Pusher presence channel modify Member-Object

Tags: laravel, pusher, laravel-echo

I use Pusher with Laravel Echo. I try to build a player online counter.
The problem is, that pusher send the whole User-Object of every user that listen to this channel.
[Members-List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWym9.png)

The problem is, that there are some sensitve informations like the api_token.
Ive tried to just send a other object like this:

```
Broadcast::channel('playerOnline', function ($player) {
return $player;
});
```

But i think that he is getting the user-objects from the authEndpoint.

Do someone know, how i can hide the user object from the other users ?
I only need to number, how many users are listen to this channel without all that user-data.

THX

Answer (score 0):

Just simply return true like below in your channel

```
return true;
```

Comment: If i just return true on this channel like:

Broadcast::channel('playerOnline', function () {
    return true;
});

Then no user-object will shown -> no user count.

Comment: if it is presence channel whenever user join the channel count it from your frontend

Comment: to count it, i need to join the channel. When you join the presence channel, you will get all information about all the other user in this channel